How do I call a method from a static context within a renderfragment Blazor
I have this renderfragment that I am assigning as a menu and I need to be able to clear the list from within this renderfragment and I can't seem to get it to work. I have tried event callbacks, actions, delagates and everytime I run into this error:   Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context. I also cannot pass any parameters through the builder it gives me this error: Cannot convert initializer type 'lambda expression' to target type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment'. So how can I clear this list in this context? The problem is within the button: ClearListAction(). This also doesnt work: OnCLick=(() => webhookList.Clear()) I get the same error about 'this'.
    public delegate void ClearWebhooksAction(); // Delegate for clearing

    public static ClearWebhooksAction ClearListAction { get; set; } // Delegate reference

    public RenderFragment menu =
        @<Menu>

            @foreach (var n in webhookList)
            
                    <div class="flex">
                        <div style="flex:20%">
                            <Avatar size="40px" src="@n.Avatar"/>
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex:65%">@n.Subtitle</div>
                    </div>
            }
            @if (webhookList.Count > 0)
            {
                ClearListAction = () => webhookList.Clear();
                <div class="dismiss">
                   <MudButton  OkClick="@(() => webhookList.Clear())">Dismiss</MudButton>
                </div>
            }
    </Menu>;

it is passed like this in my blazor code:
 <Dropdown Overlay=@menu Placement="AntDesign.Placement.Bottom" Class="notifications" Arrow>
                    <MudBadge Content="@(notificationCount)" Color="MudBlazor.Color.Primary" Overlap="true" Origin="Origin.CenterRight">
                        <Icon Type="bell" Theme="outline" OnClick="() => OpenDrawer(MudBlazor.Anchor.End)"/>
                    </MudBadge>
                </Dropdown>


Create a [mre] , without Mud and keep it as short and simple as possible. Add the exact error message and on which line. The static delegate cannot be your problem.

Ok I fixed it, the problem is the OnClick method of the MudButton. The error is coming from the OnClick as well

Better but still not very minimal. Why did you make ClearListAction static?  Because when I did a mock-up I got an error about 'field initializer' which makes more sense.

Well i thought you might want to see why i wanted to clear the list, so i left it in there I simplified the button more too, but yeah when i remove the static property i get this error so i keep it in there:   MainLayout.razor(841, 29): [CS0236] A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MainLayout.ClearListAction'

But that isnt the way I need to do it, I tried doing the OkClick like this initially: OkClick="@(() => webhookList.Clear())" ...... and was just going through other methods to implement it. I would use anything that successfully helped me clear this list in this renderfragment.

@HenkHolterman did you have any luck ive been working on it all day an i cant find anything that helps me access a method in this context

I even figured out how to pass a method as a parameter through the builder like this: RenderFragment = (clearList) => and it still throws this error about static context

@HenkHolterman nope i couldn't get it either :( guess it isnt possible but if you ever did figure it out I would love to know
